# Witnesses to conversion?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, edim-witnesses

Who must be a witness to a conversion according to Jewish law?

Answer (score 4):

The talmud quotes a baraisa from rabbi chiya bar abba in the name of rabbi yochanan that a convert must stand before three jewish men who form a beis din. (yevamos 46b) this is further recorded by maimonides in mishneh torah. (issurei biah 14:6)

Not all of those men have to be rabbis. the shulchan aruch states that three laymen can form a beis din, provided at least one of the men is knowledgeable in all the halacha. (choshen mishpat 3:1) The shach however maintains that it is a biblical obligation that all three of the men be knowledgeable. (ibid 3:1)

Nowadays it is almost universal that a convert stand before three trained rabbis.

Comment: What about the marriages of Shimshon?

Comment: There's a [line of thought](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17613/15256) that his wives were converted by _batei din_ of laymen, hence it's surprising to see that claim of the Biblical obligation.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer

Comment: @Kazibácsi I guess the shach doesn't hold by that line of thought but do bear in mind he is the minority opinion most authorities hold only one dayan needs to be knowledgeable